# Applying a function to values in dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to apply a function to all values in dict and store that in a separate dict. I am just trying to see how I can play with python and want to see how I can rewrite something like this

```
for i in d:
    d2[i] = f(d[i])
```

to something like

```
d2[i] = f(d[i]) for i in d
```

The first way of writing it is of course fine, but I am trying to figure how python syntax can be changed

Answer (score 119, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.7 or 3.x:

```
d2 = {k: f(v) for k, v in d1.items()}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
d2 = {}
for k, v in d1.items():
    d2[k] = f(v)
```

Otherwise:

```
d2 = dict((k, f(v)) for k, v in d1.items())
```

Comment: +1. Note that this is creating a new dictionary `d2` instead of modifying one in place. But this is almost always what you actually want to do. If you really do need to update `d2` in place, you can always do `d2.update({k: f(v) for k, v in d1.items()})`.

Comment: using 3.x and the second approach works nicely. exactly what I was looking for. thanks

Comment: thanks for your comment abarnert. I need to create a new dict in this case, but good to know this for other cases. thanks

Comment: @abarnert, is it possible to update the dictionary to map a function to the values of user-specifed keys rather than all keys?

Answer (score 9):

You could use `map`:

```
d2 = dict(d, map(f, d.values()))
```

If you don't mind using an extension. You can also use [`valmap`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.dicttoolz.valmap) in the [toolz](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library which is functionally equivalent to using the `map` solution:

`from toolz.dicttoolz import valmap`

```
d2 = valmap(f, d)
```

If not for the clean presentation of the method, you also have the option of supplying a default return class as well, for people that need something other than a `dict`.

Answer (score 6):

```
d2 = dict((k, f(v)) for k,v in d.items())
```

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries can be nested in Python and in this case the solution `d2 = {k: f(v) for k, v in d1.items()}` will not work.

For nested dictionaries one needs some function to transverse the whole data structure. For instance if values are allowed to be themselves dictionaries, one can define a function like:

```
def myfun(d):
  for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
      d[k] = myfun(v)
    else:
      d[k] = f(v)
  return d
```

And then

```
d2 = myfun(d)
```