# list of tuples into dictionary with same keys and its average values?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d={}

l=[(‘202010’, 100), (‘202010’, 150), (‘202011’, 102), (‘202011’, 343)]
```

I have tried this which only returns the sum:

```
for key, value in l:

        d[key] = d.get(key, value)

    print(d)
```

...

```
d={’202010‘： 250, ‘202011’: 445}
```

How can I get it in the form of this and possibly calculate the averages for each lists?

```
d={‘202010’: [100, 150], ‘202011’: [102, 343]}

d={‘202010’: [125.0],  ‘202011’: [222.5]}
```

Comment: The answer @jakub linked solves the first question, computing the average just means applying a function to each value in the dictionary, which can be easily done with a dictionary comprehension and in several other ways, also answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063691/applying-a-function-to-values-in-dict

Comment: Use ``d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)`` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
d = {}
count = {}

l = [('202010', 100), ('202010', 150), ('202011', 102), ('202011', 343)]

idx = 0
for x in l:
    if l[idx][0] in d:
        d[l[idx][0]] += l[idx][1]
        count[l[idx][0]] += 1
    else:
        d[l[idx][0]] = l[idx][1]
        count[l[idx][0]] = 1
    idx += 1

idx = 0
for x in l:
    d[l[idx][0]] = d[l[idx][0]] / count[l[idx][0]]

print(d)
```