# Is there a concise way to apply a function to a dict value in-place?

Tags: python, dictionary

Instead of `a = a + 1`, we can write `a += 1` ([augmented assignments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0203/)).

The advantage is we don't need to write `foo` twice.

In the same fashion, I would like to simplify the following *pattern*:

```
c['d'] = some_function(c['d'])
```

**Is there some function in Python's standard library that makes this possible?**

Just to illustrate what I am looking for:

I *could* write something like this (once)

```
def apply_in_place(callable, dictionary, key):
    dictionary[key] = callable(dictionary[key])
```

Which would allow me to do (in many places)

```
apply_in_place(some_function, c, 'd')
```

*However*, I've got a feeling there must be something in the standard library already, e.g. something like [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

I have not been able to find anything myself.

Please note: I am *not* asking about [Applying a function to values in dict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13063691).

Comment: The short answer is "no."

Comment: And the longer, but helpful, answer is: no, but it can be solved by using DeepSpace's solution. If the answer the new questions was always be a strict "no", humanity would still have quadratic wheels and no fire.

Comment: The difference between this and round wheels is that round wheels are actually better than what came before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You can't, due to the combination of how dictionaries, function calls and assignments work in Python. The wrapper function you showed is one of the best 2 options available. Read below for the second alternative.

---

The premise of the question is a bit off. You could use `+=` on a dict value as well if it was an integer (`dictionary[key] += 1`), and on the other hand you would have the same "problem" if you wanted to apply a function on a non-dict value (`foo = some_callable(foo)`).

In other words, the problem is not the fact that you want to apply a function to a dict value, but just that you want to apply a function.

The way I see it, you have 2 readable and non-hacky ways to achieve this:

- Create a wrapper function, **much like the one you did**, that will minimize the repetition.
- Subclass `UserDict` that will also allow you to minimize the repetition by providing an interface:

  ```
  from collections import UserDict

  class MyDict(UserDict):
      def apply(self, f, key):
          # TODO sanity check if f is not callable or if key does not exist
          self[key] = f(self[key])

  d = MyDict({'a': 'a'})
  d.apply(str.upper, 'a')
  print(d)
  ```

  outputs

  ```
  {'a': 'A'}
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure that's better than `for key in d: d[key] = func(d[key])`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It's better because that's not what OP wants :) they want to operate on a specific key

Comment: Then it's strictly worse, as all it does is use the same unwanted syntax but move it into a function. I don't see the point of the question at all.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 well, me too, and it is explained in several spots in my answer

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The one advantage of having the wrapper function/class, however, is that it allows having the repetition in a single place in the codebase, and not in every place you want to apply the function to a value

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I agree that moving the same unwanted syntax into a function does not help much. That's why I was trying to ask if there is already something in the standard library that does this. For example, something similar to `map()`. I updated the question to make this more explicit.

Comment: It seems like more or less the same amount of repetition, just with a thin function wrapper added around it. Come to think of it... why I didn't remember this before I don't know, but it seems like `dict.__setitem__` would be close to that function.

Comment: @DeepSpace: Thanks, I like your `UserDict` solution.

Comment: Overall, I think this adds no concision, speed, or clarity and is a net negative in every way.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I disagree. This saves a lot of repetition and saves you from typos. Imagine a codebase where this functionality is used in many, many places. If you need to use the name of the key twice in every line, it's asking for typos. If you have the wrapper function, you have the repetition only inside that function.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: I was just wondering if there was some *existing* way to prevent having to write the same *key* twice. The `apply_in_place()` example was just a means to explain what I was looking for.

Comment: @djvg See my previous comment. It is still preferable to have the wrapper function if you are going to do this operation a lot of times since you only repeat the key twice inside the function body. In all invocations of that function, the key will be written once.

Comment: That kind of imaginary codebase most likely has an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Why is it a "net negative" in every way? It solves the question, **thus it is a strictly net positive**. What in fact is a net negative in every way, is your commenting style. It adds nothing besides bloating this question. DeepSpace: nice solution, clear upvote from my side!

Comment: The problem is only a perceived problem, and the solution adds other problems. Subclassing dict and adding a method just for syntactic sugar that isn't any shorter just because you think a typo in the sugar is somehow less likely than a typo in the original and much shorter code adds confusion for no benefit, and if your code really does have that much repetition that's the real problem as I mentioned above. This whole thing is just bad advice and ugly code. Do whatever you want, though.